# Run different class from same java (eclipse) project

Tags: java

This "program" or "app" I'm writing is a thing I want to do to prove myself I can learn java, it's not a serious game, it's just a game for myself to see if I can do things right.

This is my current code

```
//*Importación del botón
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
//*Set de importación para sonido
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException; //Fin del set de sonido
import javax.swing.JFrame; //*Importando la ventana
import javax.swing.JLabel; //*Texto en la ventana
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants; //*Swing para alinear texto


//*Comienza el juego
public class Principal {    
public static void main(String args[]) {

//*Script original  (Añadido final para cerrarlo)
final JFrame vprincipal = new JFrame ();
JLabel texto = new JLabel("Bienvenida",SwingConstants.CENTER);

//*Añadiendo el JPanel no original
JPanel contenedor = new JPanel();
contenedor.setOpaque(true);
contenedor.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
contenedor.setLayout(null);

//*Script original
texto.setText("Bienvenidos a la versión alfa 0.1 de Mazmorra de Puertas");
texto.setLocation(500,500);
vprincipal.add(texto);
String nombre = "Mazmorra de Puertas";
vprincipal.setTitle(nombre);
vprincipal.setSize(400, 200);
vprincipal.setVisible(true);
vprincipal.setDefaultCloseOperation
(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
vprincipal.setVisible(true);
vprincipal.setLocation(750,350);
vprincipal.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

contenedor.add(texto);

//*Añadiendo botón
final JButton empezar = new JButton("Empezar");
vprincipal.setContentPane(contenedor);
contenedor.add(empezar);
empezar.setSize(100, 20);
empezar.setLocation(140, 130);

//*Comienzo del juego
final JFrame comienzo = new JFrame();
String nombre2 = "Version a0.1";
comienzo.setTitle(nombre2);
comienzo.setSize(400, 200);
comienzo.setVisible(false);
comienzo.setDefaultCloseOperation
(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
comienzo.setVisible(false);
comienzo.setLocation(750,350);
comienzo.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


//*Añadiendo acciones al botón
empezar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        vprincipal.dispose();
        comienzo.setVisible(false);





    }
});


//*Aquí se añade el sonido
try {
    AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("Intro.wav"));
    final Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audio);
    clip.start();

    empezar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            clip.stop();
        }

});
}

catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException uae) {
    System.out.println(uae);
}
catch(IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println(ioe);
}
catch(LineUnavailableException lua) {
    System.out.println(lua);
}

}

{
}
}
```

I'd like to access to GuessingGame (An example from a learning java book I'm reading) after this chunk of code:

```
//*Añadiendo acciones al botón
empezar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        vprincipal.dispose();
        comienzo.setVisible(false);
```

I've tried with new nameofclass(); and several more things that I'd take long to write here all attempts I'd try.

I'm trying to call from class `Principal` to class `GuessingGame`. How to do it when I press the button called `empezar`?

Comment: Can you provide some information about GuessingGame? It's hard to provide an appropriate solution without know a bit about the structure of this other class

Comment: How and where are you trying to call `GuessingGame`? It cannot be easily understood. Deberías colocar como parte de tu pregunta el lugar donde has intentado crear la nueva instancia de `GuessingGame`, así como la estructura de esta clase, para identificar mejor el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to run method main from another Java class (representing some game). Well, you can do it simply by calling:

```
AnotherClass.main({});
```

Assuming `AnotherClass` is the class with game you want to run.

You can also run another class in the separate process, using [ProcessBuilder API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

```
// method to start class in another JVM process
public static void startProcess(Class<?> clazz) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(clazz.getCanonicalName());
    String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
    String path = System.getProperty("java.home") + separator + "bin" + separator + "java";
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(path, "-cp", classpath, clazz.getCanonicalName());
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    process.waitFor();
}

// run in another process
startProcess(AnotherClass.class);
```

Comment: @Rush2sk8 the main method must always be static for it be an application entry point

Comment: Is starting a new process truly necessary? It seems a bit overkill for what he's trying to do

Comment: @DrewBuckley in fact, we don't know what OP wants to achieve. Maybe this `GuessingGame` class doesn't fit with the initial design and that makes this a proper solution. Until OP provides more info, we cannot be sure.

Comment: @DrewBuckley: well, that's why I described 2 possibilities: either call main directly or run it in another process.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for, I can't believe I couldn't find it anywhere, it was more simple than I thought but knowing how this works, I can go on with my minigame.

Thanks!

And yes, I was trying to call main from another class in the same java project (and package) but I didn't know how, but now I do, thanks again :)

I just had to delete the {} inside the () of the first example and got it working.